# Alternative to WebGL to render 3D in a plain HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, 3d

I'm looking for an alternative to WebGL to render moderately complex meshes (less than 10 000 triangles, often only a few hundreds). I have looked at WebGL since 2012 but it still works desperately slowly on lots of my machines, both desktop computers and laptops. I admit that my hardware is a bit aged (bought between 2007 and 2013) but all those machines are able to run numerous first person shooters (Red Eclipse, OpenArena, Urban Terror, Cube, Quake 3, ...) without any problems whereas full screen WebGL rendering remains slow except when the geometry is quite basic (some few rotating cubes).

I've found seen.js and phoria.js, are there any other Javascript library able to render 3D without WebGL with decent performance?

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the newer and more powerful glTF 2.0?

Might be exactly what you need - Khronos group developed it, and it's getting some serious traction in adoption right now - see below.

https://www.khronos.org/gltf/

From the resources and examples section of the Khronos page whose link I posted above, I find "redcube js - a ***javascript library*** for rendering webgl. RedCube is a minimalistic viewer used Khronos glTF 1.0 format."

https://github.com/Reon90/redcube

There are also a slew of other resources aggregated on that page for coders - I personally am ***not*** a coder - I'm a 3D generalist, however this, and several other similar available resources on that list certainly *say* they are libraries, including:

https://github.com/javagl/JglTF

With this listing parented beneath it:

JglTF - Java libraries for glTF

jgltf-impl - Classes representing a glTF model, auto-generated from the glTF JSON schema

jgltf-impl-v1 - glTF 1.0

jgltf-impl-v2 - glTF 2.0

jgltf-impl-v2-technique-webgl - KHR_technique_webgl extension

jgltf-model - Classes for reading, processing, converting and writing glTF

jgltf-obj - Library for converting OBJ to glTF

jgltf-viewer - Viewer for glTF, with different implementations:

jgltf-viewer-jogl - glTF viewer based on JOGL

jgltf-viewer-lwjgl - glTF viewer based on LWJGL version 2

jgltf-browser - Application combining the above libraries

jgltf-validator - Simple glTF validator, only intended for internal use

**From that github rep page I see this listing as well:**

The libraries currently available here are

jgltf-impl-v1 and jgltf-impl-v2 : A very simple set of classes that represent glTF 1.0 and 2.0 data, auto-generated from the glTF JSON schema

jgltf-model : A library built on top of jgltf-impl-v1 and jgltf-impl-v2 that offers functionality for reading glTF data and accessing the associated data in a form that is more convenient for the use in Java. It serves as a thin abstraction layer around the auto-generated classes.

jgltf-obj : A library/application for loading OBJ files and converting them into glTF 1.0 or 2.0 assets.

jgltf-browser : A simple standalone application that combines functionalities of the JglTF libraries: It allows loading glTF 1.0 or 2.0 from files or URLs via drag-and-drop, offers a basic functionality for browsing through the glTF structure, showing the images, shader code and accessor data in a structured form, importing OBJ files as glTF, and saving glTF as standard, embedded or binary glTF files.

jgltf-viewer : A base library for glTF viewers

jgltf-viewer-jogl : A glTF viewer based on JOGL
jgltf-viewer-lwjgl : A glTF viewer based on LWJGL 2
jgltf-impl-v2-technique-webgl : Auto-generated classes for the glTF 2.0 KHR_technique_webgl extension

jgltf-validator : A simple glTF validator, only intended for internal use

So, although my original response *was indeed* short and top-level, the resources I linked to were in fact relevant to the stated need for a lighter-weight, faster implementation than basic WebGL, and though I didn't previously pore through all the relevant links and repos to post them here, there were a ***lot*** of available **Javascript libraries**, published notes and documentation of dependencies.

Hopefully some of this can in fact be helpful.

Comment: Please describe how it can resolve the asker's problem. Also include an example if possible.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't resolve my problem as it's not a Javascript library, it's a 3D model storage format and the most famous Javascript library supporting it is Three.js, which relies on WebGL. Maybe I've missed something obvious, just let me know.

Comment: Might want to look at my answer as edited at this point gouessej - may be more helpful - sorry there wasn't enough detail before.